# What is cardinality and how does it affect performance (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, cardinality

We have a massive table where I need to make an update on a single row. I don't know the primary key of the row, but I have a varchar value that is unique within that table. I also have the value of a few other columns in that tables.

Running the update is taking upwards of three minutes, and I assume its doing a full table scan.

Looking at the indices on the table, the index on the column has a cardinality of zero and page count of zero. There are other indices with a cardinality equal to the number of rows in the table (couple million) and page count of a couple hundred thousand.

What do these numbers actually mean?

And as a followup, would adding a restriction that hits an index with a higher cardinality or number of pages speed up the execution? Or is there anything else I can look at on the indicies to find one that would be better suited to quickly find the row I ned to change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is cardinality in Databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621077/what-is-cardinality-in-databases)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Cardinality** is the number of unique values for that field within the table.

I suspect that SQL Server didn't actually create the index because there are no records for it.  Is is possible this field is all `NULL`s, or there is a filter on it that eliminates all records like `WHERE 1=0`?

A good place to start would be to run the update and capture the actual execution plan.

**EDIT:**

Index Type 3 is an `XML Index`.

[Please see this page for reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173760.aspx)

The structure of `XML` indexes is quite a bit different.  I don't use them myself but from some quick reading it sounds like it creates a series of additional indexes that can't be accessed directly by users but are used by the query engine.

Comment: The field is definitely not null. It has an index type of 3 ... which I'm wondering if its an unclustered index and only used to make ure that values are unique.

Comment: @Reverend - can you look at the index definition?

Comment: Yeah ... but I'm looking at it through Squirrel which only gives me a number. It says its index type 3.

Comment: @Reverend - I'm looking that up now.  I suspect it may be an `XML` index or something weird...What data is the field?

Comment: that can't be right ... it's just a string ... like a uuid (not exactly, but effectively)

Comment: It's definitely an `XML` index.

Comment: weird ... in sys.indexes it says the type is 2 ... either way it's also says its a nonclustered index which makes sense why using it doesn't improve that much performance.