# What is cardinality in Databases?

Tags: database, database-design, cardinality

Could somebody explain to me, with the help of examples, what is cardinality in databases?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

A source of confusion may be the use of the word in two different contexts - data modelling and database query optimization.

In data modelling terms, cardinality is how one table relates to another.

- 1-1 (one row in table A relates to one row in tableB)
- 1-Many (one row in table A relates to many rows in tableB)
- Many-Many (Many rows in table A relate to many rows in tableB)

There are also optional participation conditions to the above (where a row in one table doesn't *have* to relate to the other table at all).

See Wikipedia on [Cardinality (data modelling)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29).

---

When talking about database query optimization, cardinality refers to the data in a column of a table, specifically how many unique values are in it. This statistic helps with planning queries and optimizing the execution plans.

See Wikipedia on [Cardinality (SQL statements)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28SQL_statements%29).

Comment: Would a cardinality of zero mean that the two tables do not relate to each other?

Comment: Cardinality of zero? Not a term used much - but I suppose that it would mean that. Normally - there would be no line connecting such tables in an ER diagram, so no need to indicate cardinality.

Comment: Zero cardinality in data modeling is used to indicate optional relationships.  As in 0..1 or 0..n

Comment: making analogy to the maths connotation of the term cardinality:
    **(data modeling) cardinality between two tables is uniqueness of the values between two tables (cardinality as a function between two sets)     **(database query optimization) cardinality of a table is how unique the rows are for that column (cardinality of the set itself)

Answer (score 36):

It depends a bit on context.  Cardinality means the number of something but it gets used in a variety of contexts.

- When you're building a data model, cardinality often refers to the number of rows in table A that relate to table B.  That is, are there 1 row in B for every row in A (1:1), are there N rows in B for every row in A (1:N), are there M rows in B for every N rows in A (N:M), etc.
- When you are looking at things like whether it would be more efficient to use a b*-tree index or a bitmap index or how selective a predicate is, cardinality refers to the number of distinct values in a particular column.  If you have a `PERSON` table, for example, `GENDER` is likely to be a very low cardinality column (there are probably only two values in `GENDER`) while `PERSON_ID` is likely to be a very high cardinality column (every row will have a different value).
- When you are looking at query plans, cardinality refers to the number of rows that are expected to be returned from a particular operation.

There are probably other situations where people talk about cardinality using a different context and mean something else.

Answer (score 11):

> In database, **Cardinality** number of rows in the table.

[image]
[img source](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~chang/156/04reldb.html)

---

[image]
[img source](https://www.slideshare.net/NikhilDeswal/cardinality-and-participation-constraints)

---

- Relationships are named and classified by their **cardinality** (i.e. [number of elements of the set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality)).
- Symbols which appears closes to the entity is **Maximum cardinality** and the other one is **Minimum cardinality**.
- Entity relation, shows end of the **relationship line** as follows:
  [image]

[image]

image [source](http://conceptdraw.com/solution-park/resource/images/solutions/entity-relationship-diagram-(erd)/Design_Elements(Crows-Foot-ERD).png)

Answer (score 8):

Cardinality refers to the uniqueness of data contained in a column. If a column has a lot of duplicate data (e.g. a column that stores either "true" or "false"), it has low cardinality, but if the values are highly unique (e.g. Social Security numbers), it has high cardinality.

Comment: Cardinality can refer to a couple of different things, but Oded's answer is *most likely* what you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

Cardinality of a set is the namber of the elements in set
for
we have a set
a > a,b,c < so ths set contain 3 elements 
3 is the cardinality of that set

Answer (score -2):

Definition:
We have tables in database. In relational database, we have relations among the tables. These relations can be one-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many. These relations are called 'cardinality'.

Significant of cardinality:

Many relational databases have been designed following stick business rules.When you design the database we define the cardinality based on the business rules. But every objects has its own nature as well.

When you define cardinality among object you have to consider all these things to define the correct cardinality.